# Differences between Fedora servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora

I'm using Amazon EC2 and trying to choose a machine image (AMI) for my project.  It seems all their LAMP AMIs are Fedora Core 4, but this seems like quite an old version, considering the current release is apparently Fedora 12, and < 10 releases are no longer supported.

My question is how significantly different are the early fedora releases- is it crazy to be on versions 4 or even 8?

(I realize this is probably a broad question)

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2011, Fedora 14 AMI [images](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Cloud_SIG/EC2_Images) are available from the Fedora project. They are S3, not EBS images, though there has been quite a bit of [discussion](http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/cloud/2010-December/000422.html) and [guidance](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Publishing_image_to_EC2) on the Fedora mailing lists and wiki for creating EBS images as well.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you're asking, it's worth pointing out that Amazon maintains a Linux distribution specifically for EC2 that is based on Redhat, but with more current software. If you just want a Linux distro that works with EC2 and has support for installing RPM packages with `yum`, that's probably your best bet.

Since they started their own distro, Amazon got much less interested in maintaining a current version of Ubuntu, Fedora, Centos, etc. Not really any point, from their perspective.

http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Comment: @Tyler- Great follow up, thanks- While it doesn't answer the specific question, it solves the problem I was dealing with, so much appreciated.